# SwiftUI MacOS using ObservableObject to update State

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am having a State in SwiftUI Mac OS, which stores my active selection of a Navigation View. Everything is working with the Navigation view.

Now I have created a new `class` which confirms to the `Observable Object`. In some child views I will make a change to that object. When the change is done, my Navigation view updated the object aswell, which is the feature of Observable Object as far as I understand.

What I now want to achieve is that the Observable object changes my `@State` in my Navigation view.

That is my declaration in my Navigation view. UserData stores a `int` aswell, which should be set to the `selection` on change.

```
@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

@State var selection: Int?
```

So `userData.active = 2`, should set `selection = 2` aswell. Is there a onChange event I can trigger?

I am using that `@State selection` for a Binding in my Navigation Link.

```
NavigationLink(destination: SecondContentView(), tag: 0, selection: self.$selection)
{
```

**Second approach**, would be using that `userData.active : Int` directly as `State`. However, I am passing that `selection` `State` as `Binding` and it gives me an error when passing the variable of an `EnvironmentObject` as `Binding`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `UserData` directly, like

```
NavigationLink(destination: SecondContentView(), tag: 0, 
    selection: self.$userData.active)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it  wrong. I changed it to @Published var active : Int? and used your self.$userData.active and it worked :) Appreciated

Comment: Is it necesarry to declare it as optional with? .. I would want to have it != nil always

Comment: @davidev, it is declared in signature as `selection: Binding<V?>`, so yes it is required.

Comment: Thanks.. however when I use it i selection, it works fine but then when the window disappear or I click a navigation link, the active variable is set to nil.

Comment: My Int works with Tag and selection for the nav. However, if I use it afterwards after the push is completed, the value is nil? Why?

Comment: `NavigationView` has unique set of tags for every navigation stack level.

Comment: So is that tag stored in active or released after the navigation view was set? My tags are unique

Comment: make sure active is optional :)